# How do I hide numbers from a table of sudoku?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, puzzle

I'm trying to write a program that will give the user a sudoku puzzle to solve. But I'm stuck on hiding numbers by difficulty level.  How do I do that?

Comment: "Hiding numbers by difficulty level"? What's that?

Comment: have you (sis007) looked into any literature about sudoku generation? This may be better start than asking on the forum.

Comment: Well, I think it is good question, actually. As I've understood, author wants to generate Sudoku with different difficulty levels.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have a 9x9 matrix of integers

```
int sudoku[9][9];
```

and this matrix is filled with a correct Sudoku, just replace some entries by 0 for example. Remember that Sudoku are often symmetric around their centre.

```
// Hide (i,j) from solution
sudoku[i][j] = 0;
sudoku[8-i][8-j] = 0;
```

Each time you hide two numbers from the solution, check back with your solver that it can still be solved. Finally, associate difficulty with a certain amount of loops of such a process

```
for (k=0; k < difficulty; ) {
  // randomly select (i,j) so that:
  //   - 0 <= i <= 4
  //   - 0 <= j <= 4
  //   - (i,j) != (4, 4)
  //   - solution[i][j] != 0 (i.e., (i, j) has not already been randomly selected
  save1 = solution[i][j];
  solution[i][j] = 0;
  save2 = solution[8-i][8-j];
  solution[8-i][8-j] = 0;

  if (!can_be_solved(solution)) {
    // (i, j) was not a good choice!
    solution[i][j] = save1;
    solution[8-i][8-j] = save2;
  }
  else {
    // it's still OK, let's go one step further
    k += 1;
  }
}
  //

}
```

Comment: the first sudoku I saw were symmetric. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku#History) agrees with that.

Comment: I have just looked into the pile of solved sudoku and few books in my cupboard and I haven't found any with symmetry. Probably this symmetry cheat is used only in US/Japan... It's not common in Europe.

Comment: @V-X I'm french and the first sudoku I solved had symmetry. The ones available in newspapers nowadays do not respect this rule anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a sudoku solver and then just randomly generate sudoku boards and test if they are valid with your sudoku solver.  In your method that generates the boards, you could have an input that specifies the number of numbers that will be shown on the beginning board.  Take a look at the standard number of numbers for different difficulties and base it off of that.

Comment: this is not that easy. The difficulty doesn't depend only on the number of numbers but rather on the difficulty of moves required to solve that...

Comment: Yes, so you have to use feedback from the solver as to "how hard was this to solve". Since a pretty primitive solver can solve a sudoko (on my laptop) in about 2ms, I expect you can run a few times without too much difficulty. Having said that, I never finished my "make a sudoku board" for my project, because I ran into this sort of problem - and then got sidetracked with some other project that was more fun.